# How to use Perl to replace multiple lines containing character '/' and new line?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I'm trying to modify block of several lines in several files. Initially, I tried sed but read that Perl might be a better choice. However, my Perl is very basic and I'm not sure how to deal with an empty (new) line and the special character '/'. To sum things up, I'd like to have a one-liner, something like (`$perl -i -pe ...`), to convert

```
(new line)
#include <item_b/item_bC.h>
```

into

```
#include <item_a/item_aC.h>
#include <item_b/item_bC.h>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want: for every empty line to copy the next line and put it instead of that empty line? And the numbers in that next line change ... by subtracting `1`? For all numbers? For all empty lines?

Comment: Not for every empty line, only for those followed by `#include <item_b/item_bC.h>`. I don't need any arithmetic operation so let substitute the numbers by letters to make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way -- slurp the file into a string, then match a line with only possibly spaces followed by a line starting with `#include...`, and replace what's matched with that `#include` line twice

```
perl -0777 -wpe's{ ^\s*\n ( \#include.*\n ) }{$1$1}mxg' file.c
```

With `-0777` it slurps the whole file into `$_` and with `-p` it prints `$_` on every line (only once when under `-0777` since hte whole file is in `$_` so there is only one "line"); see [switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches). The `/m` modifier makes `^` (and `$`) also match line boundaries inside a (multiline) string.

Or, with the same general approach (slurp the file) but use a lookahead

```
perl -0777 -wpe's{ ^\s*\n (?= (\#include.*\n) ) }{$1}mxg' file.c
```

Matches an empty line after which a lookahead finds a line starting with `#include`, which is also captured so to replace the empty line with it.  Since [lookarounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) don't consume anything there is no need to replace that line (with itself).

Note, the `.*` is greedy and matches as much as possible up to the pattern that follows it, and here we have the whole file ahead of it so it may appear that `.*\n` will match all the way to the very last `\n` in the file! However, `.` doesn't match a line-feed (with `/s` modifier it does) so `.*\n` here stops at the first newline, so it matches the rest of the line.

If a more specific include statement need be matched add details following the `#include` pattern.<sup>†</sup>

Otherwise, one can process line by line, by copying the current line and printing it when on the next line, depending on what's on the saved and next line. There are some picky details to straighten there, not super amenable to one-liners.

Both tested with input `file.c` (Note: it does start with an empty line)

```
    
#include<item_b/item_bC.h>
#include<item_a/item_aC.h>

#include<item_c/item_cC.h>

int main() {

    return 1;
}
```

where we end up with two `item_b` and one `item_a` and two `itewm_c` includes and no empty lines, and the rest of the file is unaffected.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Special characters are mentioned so I'll comment. But please consult more complete resources, like tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) and reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). See also [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash)

Characters special for regex can mostly be matched as literal characters in a pattern when escaped with `\`.  But in this case that's not needed: the role of `/` in a regex is only to delimit the pattern, commonly given as `/.../`, but here I use `{}{}` as delimiters; so `/` isn't special here and can be used freely. For example

```
perl -0777 -wpe's{ ^\s*\n (?= (\#include<item_./.*\n) ) }{$1}mxg' file.c
```

matches lines from the input file I used, shown above.

There is clearly a more general pattern instead of `item` in the actual problem, and it's a filename. Most characters that are allowed in a filename can be used literally in a regex. Exceptions, like `.`, can be escaped, like `\.` to match a literal `.`.

For example, a string `item_bC.h`, where `bC` characters vary but `item` and `.h` are always the same, can be matched with the pattern `/item_..\.h/`.

Comment: I apologize for the delay caused by the time difference and the early Saturday morning errands. You're right: It's not treating `/` as a special character. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @afernandezody Most welcome.  Let me know if questions come up.  (Note, with `/.../` delimiters it is indeed a problem and it need be escaped to match a literal backslash, like `/item_.\/.*/`)

Comment: (I mean it need be escaped just to work, otherwise it's a syntax error, and then it matches as well)

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thank you for the edit, but the sample input file I show in the answer is indeed meant to start with an empty line, in line with what the question is asking.  (I rolled back your change but thank you again for wanting to improve the post.)